# Как задать параметры при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, url, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть ссылка с которой надо парсить данные ([https://www.epicgames.com/store/ru/browse?sortBy=releaseDate&sortDir=DESC&tag=Экшен&count=40&start=0](https://www.epicgames.com/store/ru/browse?sortBy=releaseDate&sortDir=DESC&tag=%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD&count=40&start=0)), и есть код, который должен парсить, но он выдает пустой словарь каждый раз и я уверен, что проблема в ссылке, возможно надо отдельно задавать параметры ему, вот только как это правильно сделать? Код, который надо доработать:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


HOST = 'https://www.epicgames.com'
URL = 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/ru/browse?sortBy=releaseDate&sortDir=DESC&tag=Экшен&count=40&start=0'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 YaBrowser/20.11.3.183 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return req

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-1gc10zu-DiscoverCardLayout__content')
    games = []


    for item in items:
        games.append(
            {
                'TITLE': item('div', class_='css-2ucwu'),
            }
        )
    return games


def parser():
    html = get_html(URL)
    games = []
    if html.status_code == 200:
        html = get_html(URL)
        games.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(games)
    else:
        print('Error')


parser()
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять почему у тебя ничего не работает, достаточно просто посмотреть на сам запрос.

```
file = open('test.html', 'wb')
file.write(get_html(URL).text.encode('utf-8'))
file.close()
```

Подходящие для этого решение - это Epic Store API. (Спасибо [0dminnimda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/353015/0dminnimda) за этот вариант решения). Вот код, который просматривает каталоги магазина и выводит их название.

```
import requests

endpoint = "https://graphql.epicgames.com/graphql"


# В переменной query содержится сам запрос
query = b'{"query":"\\n            query storefrontDiscoverQuery(\\n              $locale:String,\\n              $country:String\u0021\\n            )  {\\n              Storefront {\\n                storefrontModules(locale: $locale) {\\n                  ... on StorefrontBreaker {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    titleGroup\\n                    description\\n                    backgroundColors\\n                    layout\\n                    link {\\n                      src\\n                      linkText\\n                    }\\n                    image {\\n                      src\\n                      alt\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontFreeGames {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontCardGroup {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    link {\\n                        src\\n                        linkText\\n                    }\\n                    offers {\\n                      namespace\\n                      id\\n                      offer {\\n                        \\n          title\\n          id\\n          namespace\\n          description\\n          keyImages {\\n            type\\n            url\\n          }\\n          seller {\\n              id\\n              name\\n          }\\n          urlSlug\\n          items {\\n            id\\n            namespace\\n          }\\n          customAttributes {\\n            key\\n            value\\n          }\\n          categories {\\n            path\\n          }\\n          price(country: $country) {\\n            totalPrice {\\n              discountPrice\\n              originalPrice\\n              voucherDiscount\\n              discount\\n              fmtPrice(locale: $locale) {\\n                originalPrice\\n                discountPrice\\n                intermediatePrice\\n              }\\n            }\\n            lineOffers {\\n              appliedRules {\\n                id\\n                endDate\\n              }\\n            }\\n          }\\n          linkedOfferId\\n          linkedOffer {\\n            effectiveDate\\n            customAttributes {\\n              key\\n              value\\n            }\\n          }\\n        \\n                      }\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontFeaturedCarousel {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    slides {\\n                      title\\n                      eyebrow\\n                      description\\n                      backgroundColor\\n                      image {\\n                        src\\n                        alt\\n                      }\\n                      mobileImage {\\n                        src\\n                        alt\\n                      }\\n                      link {\\n                        src\\n                        linkText\\n                      }\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontTiles {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    tiles {\\n                      label\\n                      genre\\n                      link {\\n                        src\\n                        linkText\\n                      }\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                }\\n              }\\n            }\\n            ","variables":{"locale":"ru-RUS","country":"RUS"}}'

data = requests.post(endpoint, headers={"Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                                        }, data=query)
data = data.json()

print('Games:')
for slides in data['data']['Storefront']['storefrontModules']: #Перебирае категории игр (На распродажах, бесплатные игры и т.д.)
    if len(slides) > 0:
        try: # Проверяем если в категории игры
            for game in slides['offers']:
                print(game['offer']['title']) # Если есть то выводим
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: не единственным, если вы посмотрите на запросы, то увидите, что можно воспользоваться их api, что будет лаконичнее и быстрее

Comment: я говорил про `https://www.epicgames.com/graphql`, это их api, к которому делает запросы сайт, при погрузке контента

Comment: данный код парсит только названия и только на основной странице эпиков, есть какой то способ, чтоб он парсил только ссылки во вкладке "все игры", я просто сам не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй отследить запрос который посылает сам сайт серверу, скопировать curl и вставить его https://curl.trillworks.com

Даст тебе подробный запрос с куками хедером и параметрами в валидном виде